Can API Gateway with Lambda only response a JSON string type body?
I am using API Gateway with Python lambda. I created the openapi.yml as below code:
  responses:
    "200":
      description: "200 response"
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              type: object
              properties:
                table_id:
                  type: integer
                  format: int64
                table_name:
                  type: string

I am returning below code from python lambda:
 response = [{
  "table_id": 2323,
  "table_name":"test_table_1"
 },
 {
  "table_id": 1234,
  "table_name":"test_table_2"
 }]

 return { 
           "statusCode": 200,
           "headers": {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
           "body": response
           };

Now with the above code, I am getting 502 error- execution failed due to configuration error. Malformed Lambda proxy response. Which tells me that my response format is incorrect. However, when I check my lambda response and openapi.yml specs it looks fine.
However when I do  "body": json.dumps(response) it works perfectly.
Do we always need to stringify response objects when using lambda or I am missing something here?

This is because API Gateway expects the response body to be a string, not a list.
Try to use json.dumps, you can convert the response list into a JSON string
 return { 
       "statusCode": 200,
       "headers": {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
       "body": json.dumps(response)
       };


obviously you have to add import json

I am already using dumps and thought it was a workaround. Can't we use a list as responses defined in openapi.yml? Is there a way?
